# how to find out the region between two surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Describe the region cut out of the ball $x^2+y^2+z^2\le4$ by the elliptic cylinder $2x^2+z^2=1$ i.e the region inside the cylinder and ball

I equated $4-x^2-y^2=1-2x^2$ getting $y^2-x^2=3$. I guessed the region has to be

$\sqrt{1-2x^2}\le z \le \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$, $-\sqrt{y^2-3}\le x \le\sqrt{y^2-3},-\sqrt{3} \le x\le \sqrt{3} $.

I am not sure if I am on the right path. I don't understand how to get theses regions analytically since it is very difficult to see these regions graphically by hand which was the case for two dimensional objects.

Is there any fool proof method for seeing the regions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to describe the region in $1/4$ of all space, i.e; $$x\ge0, z\ge0$$ then it becomes:

$$\sqrt{1-2x^2}\le z \le \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2},~~ 0\leq x\leq\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},~~-\sqrt{x^2+3}\le y \le\sqrt{x^2+3}\\ 0\le z \le \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2},~~ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\leq x\leq 2,~~-\sqrt{x^2+3}\le y \le\sqrt{x^2+3}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
We'll denote with ${\cal I}$ the requested answer.

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}&\equiv
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> \Theta\pars{4 - x^{2} - y^{2} - z^{2}}\Theta\pars{1 - 2x^{2} - z^{2}}\,
> \dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{1 - 2x^{2} - z^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd z\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{\bracks{4 - x^{2} - z^{2}} - y^{2}}\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{1 - 2x^{2} - z^{2}}
> \Theta\pars{4 - x^{2} - z^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd z
> \int_{-\root{\vphantom{\Large A}4- x^{2} - z^{2}}}
> ^{\root{\vphantom{\Large A}4- x^{2} - z^{2}}}\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&=
> 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{1 - 2x^{2} - z^{2}}
> \Theta\pars{4 - x^{2} - z^{2}}\root{\vphantom{\Large A}4- x^{2} - z^{2}}
> \,\dd x\,\dd z
> \\[3mm]&=
> 16\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{1 - 8x^{2} - 4z^{2}}
> \Theta\pars{1 - x^{2} - z^{2}}\root{\vphantom{\Large A}1- x^{2} - z^{2}}
> \,\dd x\,\dd z
> \end{align}

Whith the change of variables $x \equiv \rho\cos\pars{\theta}$,
$z \equiv \rho\sin\pars{\theta}$ $\pars{~0 \leq \rho\,,\ 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi~}$, we'll get
\begin{align}
{\cal I}&=
16\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\,\rho\root{1- \rho^{2}}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\Theta\pars{1 - 4\rho^{2}\bracks{2\cos^{2}\pars{\theta} - \sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}}
\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
8\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\,\root{1 - \rho}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\Theta\pars{1 - 8\rho + 12\rho\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
8\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\,\root{1 - \rho}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\Theta\pars{\sin^{2}\pars{\theta} - {8\rho - 1 \over 12\rho}}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
16\pi\int_{0}^{1/8}\root{1 - \rho}\,\dd\rho
+
8\int_{1/8}^{1}\dd\rho\,\root{1 - \rho}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\Theta\pars{\sin^{2}\pars{\theta} - {8\rho - 1 \over 12\rho}}\,\dd\theta\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Let's perform the angular $\pars{~\mbox{over}\ \theta~}$ integration
> $\pars{~\mbox{notice that}\ \bracks{8\rho - 1}/\bracks{12\rho} < 1\ \mbox{when}\
> \rho > 0 ~}$:
> \begin{align}
> &\int_{0}^{2\pi}
> \Theta\pars{\sin^{2}\pars{\theta} - {8\rho - 1 \over 12\rho}}\,\dd\theta
> =
> 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
> \Theta\pars{\sin^{2}\pars{\theta} - {8\rho - 1 \over 12\rho}}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=
> 4\int_{\arcsin\pars{\root{\vphantom{\huge A}\bracks{8\rho - 1}/\bracks{12\rho}}}}^{\pi/2}\dd\theta
> =
> 4\bracks{{\pi \over 2} - \arcsin\pars{\root{8\rho - 1 \over 12\rho}}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> 2\pi - 4\arcsin\pars{\root{8\rho - 1 \over 12\rho}}
> \end{align}

By replacing this result in $\pars{1}$, we'll get:
\begin{align}
{\cal I}&=
16\pi\int_{0}^{1}\root{1 - \rho}\,\dd\rho
-
32\int_{1/8}^{1}\dd\rho\,\root{1 - \rho}\arcsin\pars{\root{8\rho - 1 \over 12\rho}}
\\[3mm]&=
24\pi - 32\underbrace{\int_{1/8}^{1}\root{1 - \rho}
\arcsin\pars{\root{{2 \over 3} - { 1 \over 12\rho}}}\,\dd\rho}
_{\ds{\approx\ 0.387853}}
\end{align}
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large{\cal I} = 62.9869}
$$

Comment: I am unable to find the boundaries.